# A Five City Loop, starting and ending in MA

Tags: no-computers, geography

Complete a loop of five large cities.

The starting city name starts with the letters **MA**. Each of the following cities starts with the last two letters of the previous city name. (Like PAR**IS** **IS**TANBUL etc.).  The fifth city name ends in **MA**, completing the loop.

All cities have population of at least 1 million according to many websites.

> I understand there could be more than one answer. My answer has
> majority of cities from Asia.

Comment: I wonder what the longest such loop we can find?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I was able to get 7 but one of them was not over 1 million.

Comment: Do you have a list of available cities? I could write a program to search for the longest cycle.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I looked at the attached list. https://data.mongabay.com/cities_pop_01.htm

Comment: Should the answer contain cities from Asia only or I can use cities from different continents?

Comment: Any continents @NilayGhosh as long as population > 1 million

Comment: Manama (Bahrain) regrets that it has but 200,000 people, for it could save you a lot of travel.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky so, you have the longest cycle?

Comment: I couldn't understand which cities are over 1M from that list as there are 3 different population numbers for each city...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came up with this, though I have to admit I had to check the number of inhabitants of the last one:

> MAnilLA - LAgOS - OSaKA - KAracHI - HIroshiMA

Answer (score 4):

I used a depth-first-search program to find all possible chains of length 5. I used this list of cities: https://worldpopulationreview.com/world-cities

> marseille leshan ankara ranchi hiroshima
>  matola lagos osaka karachi hiroshima
>  manila lagos osaka karachi hiroshima
>  ma'anshan antalya yaounde delhi hiroshima
>  ma'anshan anshan ankara ranchi hiroshima
>  malappuram amman ankara ranchi hiroshima
>  mashhad addisababa basra ranchi hiroshima
>  mashhad addisababa bamako kochi hiroshima
>
>  It is interesting that they all end with hiroshima.

For a bit of fun I also wanted to find the longest chain possible. I only ran it for a few minutes and I am sure longer chains are possible. I found one with 57 cities:

> manila lahore recife fes esfahan antalya yaounde delhi hiroshima mashhad addammam amman anshan antananarivo volgograd adana natal aleppo porto tolucadelerdo douala lagos oslo lome merida dallas astana nairobi bishkek ekurhuleni ningbo bobo bogota tampico cordoba baoji jiddah ahmedabad addisababa baku kumasi siliguri riodejaneiro rome mecca casablanca cali lille leondelosaldamas asuncion onitsha hargeysa samarinda daegu guwahati tiruchirappalli lima

Comment: The page you link to doesn't list Mexico, which you use.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question, which sought a loop of _five_ cities.

Comment: msh210 is right on that Mexico is not a city, but "Mexico City" is.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have fixed all the problems.

Comment: @NilayGhosh thank you! I like your answer too.

Comment: "No-computers" tag?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Alas, I couldn't find a 5-city chain but</strike> I did find a 6-city chain.

> Maracaibo -> Bogota -> Tangshan/Taiyuan -> Ankara -> Ranchi -> Hiroshima

---

**Update**: I found a 5-city chain but I tweaked a little bit. I used the old name for one of the cities:

> Madras(old name for Chennai)-> Aswan -> Ankara -> Ranchi -> Hiroshima

Comment: Hello @Nilay Ghosh. Rot 13 (Fgneg jvgu Znvqhthev, n Avtrevna Pvgl, naq lbh fubhyq trg vg va 5 fgrcf,)

Comment: I had never heard of Ranchi, but using that, combining with my previous answer I could get to 7: ZNavyYN - YNtBF - BFnXN - XNmNA - NAxnEN - ENapUV - UVebfuvZN

Comment: @Bart-JanvanRossum Yes, you could go to seven. I have thought of another chain but one of them has below 1 million population.

Comment: @DrD rot 13(Ohg znvqhthev unf cbchyngvba bs fvk uhaqerq gubhfnaq. )

Comment: Jung vf gur cbchyngvba bs Znvqhthev? Nafjre: Znvqhthev, Avtrevn (Nqzvavfgengvir havg: Obeab) - ynfg xabja cbchyngvba vf ≈ 1 112 400 (lrne 2015). Guvf jnf 0.611% bs gbgny Avtrevn cbchyngvba. Vs cbchyngvba tebjgu engr jbhyq or fnzr nf va crevbq 2006-2015 (+1.51%/lrne), Znvqhthev cbchyngvba va 2021 jbhyq or: 1 217 434*. This is from population.city web site.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this answer is a bit of cheating since it uses a non-English spelling for one of the cities (however, the question does not explicitly state that the names of the cities should be in English):

> **Makka** (native Arabic version of Mecca, Saudi Arabia - also spelled Makkah, but this is obviously unsuitable) -> **Kazan** (Russia) -> **Ankara** (Turkey) -> **Ranchi** (India) -> **Hiroshima** (Japan).

Comment: It's not just that that's not its English name. That's not its Arabic name either. That's a _transliteration_ of its Arabic name. Its actual Arabic name is مكة‎.